# Is there any way to add extension on Project Explorer to create new wizard project?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, eclipse-plugin

[image]

Is it possible to add my specific project wizard under "Create a project..." part?

I added for right click "new" like this

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
  <commonWizard
          type="new"
          wizardId="com.XXX.projectWizard">
          <enablement></enablement>
  </commonWizard>
  </extension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view will add 'Create new xxxx' lines at the start of this list for new project wizards which are declared as a `newWizardShortcut` for the current perspective using the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions"> 
    <perspectiveExtension 
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective"> 
        <newWizardShortcut id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewProjectCreationWizard"/>
```

The new wizard must be a project wizard.

This also adds the wizard to the top level of the 'New' menu in the projects section.

Comment: I have this already. It does not work the place i want to put it. :/